# How to use over - partition by query in SQL in order to get the current, average, and maximum value?

Tags: sql, postgresql, window-functions

I have this table where it shows a point that was being done by a device at an area and specific location.

```
working_date    device   points   area   location
19-06-2020        a        1       x       xa   
19-06-2020        a        2       x       xa 
19-06-2020        a        3       x       xa 
19-06-2020        a        4       x       xa
20-06-2020        a        5       x       xa
20-06-2020        a        6       x       xa
20-06-2020        a        7       x       xa
20-06-2020        a        8       x       xa
20-06-2020        a        9       x       xa
```

I want to get the current, average and also maximum points grouped by area and also location. If I choose any day, the current qty will show the quantity of the latest working date. Meanwhile, average quantity will show the overall average in which the devices were working. Lastly, the maximum qty will show the overall maximum point that being done by the devices.

Based on my table aboves, if I choose 21-06-2020 then the desired results:

```
working_date  area  location   device   current_qty  avg_qty   max_qty
21-06-2020     x       xa        a         5           4,5        5
```

the average qty is from total_qty / total_of_date, while the maximum qty is from the maximum quantity from all dates.

The query I have built so far was:

```
select t1.working_date, t1.device, t1.area, t1.location, t1.points_qty, t1.total_date,
sum(t1.pile_qty) over(partition by t1.working_date) / sum(t1.total_date) over(partition by t1.working_date) as avg_qty,
max(t1.pile_qty) over(partition by t1.working_date) as max_qty
from (
select working_date, device, points, area, location, count(points) as points_qty, count(distinct working_date) as total_date 
from table1 group by device, area, location
group by working_date, device, points, area, location) t1
group by working_date, device, points, area, location, pile_qty, total_date
```

with the query above, I got:

```
working_date  area  location   device   current_qty  avg_qty   max_qty
21-06-2020     x       xa        a         5           5          5
```

How should I write my query in order to get the desired results?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your desired output shows the 21st, which is not available in the sample data. So it is hard to understand the calculated data...

Comment: It means, if I choose any day, the desired result will always give me the latest working_date

Comment: Where does the qty value come from?

Comment: by counting the points

Comment: I don't know PostgreSQL, but in MS SQL Server aggregate functions return same data type as aggregated column; I would suggest use something like `sum(...) * 1.0 / sum(...)`.

Comment: @nomnom3214 Please check my answer and let me does it serve your purpose or still something is missing . Best Wishes.:-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, I have solution for you. However, I am not sure about the answer will provide the  correct result in different scenarios. Here is my code below=>
Please check the link=>[DB-FIDDLE LINK](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/fenUG3NwE3rZqQ27V21gNh/0).

```
WITH CTE AS
    (
      SELECT working_date,area,location,device, 
             COUNT(working_date) GrpCount
      FROM MYTable 
      GROUP BY working_date,area,location,device
    
    ),y AS
    (SELECT area,location,device,GrpCount,
           (SELECT GrpCount FROM CTE WHERE working_date<TO_DATE('21-06-2020','DD-MM-YYYY') ORDER BY working_date DESC LIMIT 1)  current_qty  
    FROM CTE
    )
    SELECT TO_DATE('21-06-2020','DD-MM-YYYY'),area,location,device, 
           MAX(current_qty) current_qty,
           string_agg(GrpCount::text, ',') avg_qty,
           Max(GrpCount) max_qty
    FROM Y
    GROUP BY area,location,device
```

**Note:**-Here, you can see, for `current_qty` I have used your input date `21-06-2020` like `(SELECT GrpCount FROM CTE WHERE working_date<TO_DATE('21-06-2020','DD-MM-YYYY') ORDER BY working_date DESC LIMIT 1)  current_qty` to find current qty. And it gives me your expected result. Please check the code with different range of date range and data.

Answer (score 1):

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=6f05d8a5e3b892bb5b1012681710cf87)

```
SELECT
    *,
    AVG(current_qty) OVER () as avg_qty,             -- 2
    MAX(current_qty) OVER () as max_qty
FROM (
    SELECT 
        working_date,
        area,
        location,
        device,
        COUNT(*) as current_qty                      -- 1
    FROM mytable
    GROUP BY working_date, device, area, location    -- 1
) s
WHERE working_date <= '2020-06-21'                   -- 3
ORDER BY working_date DESC
LIMIT 1
```

1. Do a normal group on the `working_date` values to calculate the date's `qty` values.
2. Use these `qty` values of the entire grouped data set to add the `avg` and `max` qty values to the records using unlimited window functions
3. To find the most recent data set to a given date: Filter all records which have the same or a smaller date value, order the most recent of these dates to the top and return only the top-most using a limit.

---

The grouping only works properly if your values for area, location and device are the same for each record as in your example. If they differ, you can use the `COUNT()` as window function instead of group aggregate to add the value to each record:

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=4de1e49f03eebec905efb0757cd8a015)

```
SELECT
    *,
    AVG(current_qty) OVER () as avg_qty,
    MAX(current_qty) OVER () as max_qty
FROM (
    SELECT 
        working_date,
        area,
        location,
        device,
        COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY working_date) as current_qty
    FROM mytable
) s
WHERE working_date <= '2020-06-21'
ORDER BY working_date DESC
LIMIT 1
```

However, in that case it is not clear, which of the five records for the `2020-06-20` group should be fetched. You must apply your order criterion to order the expected one to the top.

Comment: Did the answers help in any way? Then please don't forget to UPVOTE them! If one answer completely solves your problem, please don't forget to ACCEPT it additionally to close the question.